# I haven't learned about frameworks yet. Problem with yiiframework PHP

Tags: php, yii

I have a problem with yiiframework, I want to change the layout of the content of the web page and I can't find where to do it, because there is no index.html file to swap the  containers. Who could lead the way?

Answer (score 1):

### Premise

There are 2 versions of yii. Here follow details for yii2 since yii1, even if still maintained, is quite old and probably is not your case.

### Some introduction

Yii2 has 2 official project template,the following apply to both and basic and advanced.

If you do not know which one you use, it is easy to understand.
While basic has folders for controllers, models, views, config etc. etc. at project root, in advanced these folders are in subfloder named **frontend** and **backend**. Each folder represent different application which can share **common** element (ie models, components, controllers...).

### Generally speaking, to find the view.

Normally, each folder match the controller name and the file name in it to the controller action. Keep in mind that basic routing in yii match controller_name/action_method. So normally if you look for the view that correspond to htt://localhost/user/profile look in controllers folder of the app for UserController.php in it for actionProfile() method.

**Generally speaking because** there can be exception to this, like personalize routing rule by config, routing path handled by module, different view specified directly in the action method

**Then where are the views and layouts?**

- views/layouts (in default configuration) has the general app layout
- views/<controller_name> is the folder that correspond to the controller containing single page view.
- views/<controller_name>/<action_name>.php is the file that correspond to the view

Keep in mind that the above is a convention, so it is up to the developer to follow it. It can be different in your project.

Consider also that a view can include other view files, so it is possible you need to dig a bit to find what you are looking for.

**How to quickly find the file**

You can use search in file. Normally, each view contains specific text (fixed not dynamic one) that other views do not have. Try to search the files for that text.

### Final Note

Yii2 has a very good [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en) ([views](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-views)) and an active community that give support both trough [forum](https://forum.yiiframework.com/) and [slack](https://www.yiiframework.com/go/slack)